# Access PHP Array - name defined by $_GET

Tags: php, arrays

I'm currently stuck with accessing an array, where the name of the array is defined by $_GET.

If I have the following arrays:

```
$test = array('Hello', 'Apples', 'Green');
$AnotherArray = array('Blue', 'Sun');
```

Then I want to display the array $test, when I open my script like this:

```
ajax.php?arrayName=test
```

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: Please consider what this might mean, you're giving users direct access to your code, a solution which checks `arrayName` for _specific_ names and checks accordingly is probably better. **ALWAYS SANITIZE YOUR INPUT**

Comment: Please take the answers with a grain of salt, and keep security and simplicity in mind.  Generally you can almost always avoid variable variables, and certainly you should always avoid them in conjunction with user input, the majority of answers here aside.  Your question format did kind of beg this type of answer, unfortunately, but try simpler solutions!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You *could* accomplish this with [variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php):

```
$the_array = ${$_GET['arrayName']};
```

**Important**

This is like working with dynamite, because a malicious user can easily swap the variable name with something else and wrack your app.

A best practice is to white-list the variable name first:

```
$safe_vars = array('test', 'AnotherArray');
if (in_array($_GET['arrayName'], $safe_vars, true)) {
    $the_array = ${$_GET['arrayName']};
}
```

**Alternative**

As [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16401084/access-php-array-name-defined-by-get/16401164?noredirect=1#comment23511620_16401164) by [Pekka 웃](https://stackoverflow.com/users/187606/pekka), you could also consider having the accessible arrays inside one mother array:

```
$arrays = array(
    'test' => array('Hello', 'Apples', 'Green'),
    'AnotherArray' = array('Blue', 'Sun')
);

if (isset($arrays[$_GET['arrayName']])) {
    $the_array = $arrays[$_GET['arrayName']];
}
```

The good thing here is that no magic is used, just simple array dereferencing.

Comment: @Pekka웃 Added a good practice to my answer.

Comment: That looks like the nicest approach. (Or having an array of arrays, and allowing access only to its elements)

Answer (score 5):

Please do not use variable variables for this simple task:

Generally, just use the "arrayName" or a similar parameter as a suggestion only, and don't use the user input directly, to keep secure.

In this case, I would actually simply suggest using an integer:

```
url?showdata=1 //Shows the $test array
```

and

```
url?showdata=2 // Shows the $AnotherArray
```

etc

```
url?showdata=3 // Shows another array of your choice
```

Or if you must complicate things, just check whether the ?arrayName=something exactly equals 'test' or **exactly** equals 'AnotherArray' and then use the array specified.

Again, variable variables are a level of complexity and trouble that you're likely to regret for this simple situation!

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
$test = array('Hello', 'Apples', 'Green');
$AnotherArray = array('Blue', 'Sun');

if( $_GET['arrayName'] == 'test')
{
   print_r($test);
}
else if( $_GET['arrayName'] == 'AnotherArray')
{
   print_r($AnotherArray);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the variable variable, but it is very important to limit this only to the 'safe' variable names.

in this example i show 2 ways of making this a safe way of using a variable variable.

```
<?

$_GET['arrayName'] = 'test';

$test = array('Hello', 'Apples', 'Green');
$AnotherArray = array('Blue', 'Sun');

// safety check. only allow defined arrays from this list. Check with array of allowed names.
$possibleArrays = array('test', 'AnotherArray');

if(array_search($_GET['arrayName'], $possibleArrays) !== false)
{
    var_dump($$_GET['arrayName']);
}
else
{
    echo "warning, accessing undefined array";
}

// safety check, only allow my defined arrays. Check with switch statement.
switch($_GET['arrayName'])
{
    case 'test':
    case 'AnotherArray':
        var_dump($$_GET['arrayName']);
        break;
    default:
        echo "warning, accessing undefined array";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [variable variable names](http://php.net/language.variables.variable.php):

```
$allowedArrayNames = array( 'test', 'AnotherArray' );

if( in_array( $_GET['arrayName'], $allowedArrayNames ) && isset( $$_GET['arrayName'] ) )
{
    print_r( $$_GET['arrayName'] );
}
```

Comment: This is dangerous. It could provide access to other, private variables inside the script.

Comment: @Pekka웃 Sure, but that wasn't the question.

Comment: @feeela `eval` on the `$_GET` variable would solve the question too, would you suggest it based on the same logic?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum No. I've updated the answer to provide an alternative.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just extract? This way you don't allow access to other variables and only execute code when the variable is known?

```
extract($_GET);
print_r($$arrayName);
```

Could even add a prefix to help keep things clean.

```
extract($_GET,EXTR_PREFIX_ALL,"get_");
print_r($$get_arrayName);
```

Answer (score -1):

have you tried the following :

```
$$_GET["arrayName"]
```

Comment: This is dangerous. It could provide access to other, private variables inside the script.

Comment: Why the downvote ? He didn't ask if it was safe, and we have no idea if he sanitized his code or not. The answer is the proper answer to the question...

Comment: I didn't cast the vote, but I totally agree with it - "he didn't ask if it was safe" isn't a good defense for demonstrating a bad practice. This is a public place, people of all knowledge levels learn from what we post here.

Answer (score -1):

You could use variable variables, something like this:

```
$arrayNameGiven = $_GET['arrayName'];    // e.g. "test"
echo $$arrayNameGiven[1];    // "Apples"
```

Read more here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

Comment: It's like you didn't even read the other answers, and the problem with this sort of thing before posting. Not only does this post a security risk, it adds nothing over other answers that were already posted. I know you just wanted to help but _please_ read other answers and comments before adding another answer and make sure your answer adds something substential to them.

Comment: To _upvoter_ , why would you __encourage__ this bad behavior? The goal of this is to _imrpove_ this community, your actions are _counter-productive_ to stackoverflow.

Comment: @Benjamin Gruenbaum, in my defense: There were no other answers when I entered mine. But you are certainly right.